Maven/Java File Storage
I am working on a project using Maven, and I was a little confused on what the right way to store files for access in this program would be?
I have looked at using Maven resources, but I am not super experienced with Maven and it seems like it could be difficult to make regular create/update/delete actions to this folder.
I am currently using java.io & openCSV, but don't know if this is the recommended solution.
This is an example of how I would write to a csv:
public void writeCSV(){
    File file = new File("\\example.csv");

    String[] row1 = {"101","Joe","Joe@email.com"}
    String[] row2 = {"102","Ben","Ben@email.com"}
    String[] row3 = {"103","Jill","Jill@email.com"}

    String[][] csvRows = new String[3][];
    csvRows[0] = row1;
    csvRows[1] = row2;
    csvRows[2] = row3;

    String[] headers = {"id", "name","email"};
    csvOut(headers,csvRows,file);
}

private void csvOut(String[] headers, String[][] rows, File file){
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    CSVWriter cw = new CSVWriter(fw);

    cw.writeNext(headers);

    for(String[] row : rows){
        cw.writeNext(row);
    }
    cw.close();
    fw.close();
}

This is my method for deleting some of the data files:
public void deleteSaveData(){
        String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File datDir = new File(workingDir+"\\data");
        File csvDir = new File(workingDir+"\\csv");
        for(File dat: datDir.listFiles((File f) -> f.getName().endsWith("dat"))){
            dat.delete();
        }
        for(File csv: csvDir.listFiles((File f) -> f.getName().endsWith("csv"))){
            csv.delete();
        }
    }

This seems to work as of right now, but I don't know if this would break once exported as a jar to other systems. Would it be advised to rewrite this with the Maven method, or maybe there is some other better standard?
Any advice welcome!
Edit:
I am specifically looking for how I should save and read files during run-time.

Have you tried it on other systems?

@LajosArpad I have not yet, I am still in development for this, and I just was looking for advice before I start troubleshooting on other systems.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you talking about writing files at compile-time? At run-time?

"Would it be advised to rewrite this with the Maven method" - what do you mean by the "Maven method"? Also what is dest and why are you passing unused parameter file? Or is it a typo?

@BasilBourque I am asking about writing files at run-time.

@k314159 sorry I rewrote this section of code from a large method as it seemed too large to post here, so some of the things are a little off. I will fix that. I saw a few posts about using Maven and added resources to the pom, but I wasn't exactly sure how it worked.

Duplicate of File Write in resource folder in jar

@BasilBourque I don't think this is a duplicate, since the example code shows attempts to write to a file in either the root directory (new File("\\example.csv")) or the current working directory (System.getProperty("user.dir")). Nowhere is the OP attempting to write to a file on the classpath.

The use of Maven is irrelevant to writing files at runtime. Maven is just a build tool. It can create an application packaged as a jar file, but this application works just the same as it does inside your IDE, as long as you're not writing to your source folder (which you don't seem to be doing). Thorbjørn's answer looks correct to me, albeit a bit too brief.

@k314159 thank you for the clarification. I believe this is exactly what I was confused about.

You should not use resources as those end up on the classpath which for all practical purposes is read-only.
Use regular files or a database depending on your needs.

By default, build tools like Maven, Gradle, or common Java practice will copy all files from src/main/resources to the root of target/classes or build/classes.
You should use:
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);

rather than:
new File("\\example.csv");


If you face any issue with above one, alternatively you can use:
  InputStream getFileFromResourceAsStream(String fileName) {

    // The class loader that loaded the class
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);

    // the stream holding the file content
    if (inputStream == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("file not found! " + fileName);
    } else {
      return inputStream;
    }
  }

NOTE: Files in the JARs are considered read-only.

Files in the JARs are considered read-only. You have to create a file at some user or installation directory based location (or a location chosen by the user). 1

You can load your file from the Resource folder and rewrite in temporary location by
File f = File.createTempFile("example", ".csv");


Sorry if this is a stupid question, but would getResourceAsStream() work the same with CSVWriter as I have it done currently?

This gets a resource as an InputStream, which is only useful for reading.

@k314159 how would I output the resource then? Do I keep my method for writing but just replace the reading?

Answer is incorrect. Question shows clearly that the file has to be read as well as written. Resources cannot be written to.

@user207421 thanks for highling. I've added a note, and alternative as well.

The OP is 'specifically looking for how [he] should save and read files during run-time'. Not the other way around. Answer is still basically irrelevant.
